# Why does tap tool not work with HoloViews DynamicMap?

Tags: python, holoviews

With HoloViews/Bokeh Renderer (Holoviews = 1.11.2 / Bokeh 1.0.4 via current anaconda on Windows), I want to create a layout which consist of a scatter plot and RGB image. The scatter plot shows values of light-dark contrast in a movie. The RGB image shows a screenshot coming from the movie. The goal is to be able to click on a point in the scatter plot and the image from that time stamp in the movie is loaded.

[image]

Everything works well as long as the scatter plot is not more than a `hv.Points` Element associated with a tap tool and a selection1D stream.

```
%%opts Points [width=1108, size_index=2, tools=['hover', 'tap'], toolbar='left'] (alpha=0.2)
%%opts RGB [toolbar='left']

scatter = hv.Points(il_colful, kdims=['frame', 'bin'], vdims=['pixels', 'time'])

tap_point = streams.Selection1D(source=scatter)

def frmimg(index):
    if index:
        frame = il_colful.iloc[index[0]]['frame']
        url = './il_divo/frames/576p30/il_divo_' + '{0:05}'.format(frame) + '.png'
    else:
        url = './il_divo/frames/576p30/il_divo_00100.png'
    return hv.RGB.load_image(url).options(height=480, width=1108, xaxis=None, yaxis=None)

(hv.DynamicMap(frmimg,
     streams=[tap_point])
     + scatter).cols(1)
```

However, when I turn the scatter plot into a DynamicMap (because I want offer interactive modification for some of the scatter plots parameters) I can not use the tap tool on the scatter plot any longer, I do not get any crosshair symbol on the scatter plot and I am not able to make any selections).

```
points = hv.Points(il_colful1, kdims=['frame', 'bin'])
selected = streams.Selection1D(source=points)

def scatter(div=5000, thrsh=0, alpha=0.1):
    global points
    il_colful1['scaler'] = (il_colful1['pixels'] / div).round(0).astype(int)
    il_colful_lim1 = il_colful1[il_colful1['pixels'] > thrsh]
    points = hv.Points(il_colful_lim1, kdims=['frame', 'bin'], vdims=['pixels', 'time', 'scaler'], label='Il Divo').opts(tools=['tap'], width=1000, color='blue', size_index='scaler', fill_alpha=alpha, line_alpha=alpha)
    return points

def img(index):
    if index:
        frame = il_colful1.iloc[index[0]]['frame']
        url = './il_divo/frames/576p30/il_divo_' + '{0:05}'.format(frame) + '.png'
    else:
        url = './il_divo/frames/576p30/il_divo_00100.png'
    return hv.RGB.load_image(url).options(height=433, width=1000, xaxis=None, yaxis=None)

il_divo_sct = hv.DynamicMap(scatter, kdims=['div', 'thrsh', 'alpha']).redim.range(div=(500, 15000), thrsh=(0, 50000), alpha=(0.01, 1.0)).opts(tools=['tap'])
screenshot = hv.DynamicMap(img, streams=[selected])

(screenshot + il_divo_sct).cols(1)
```

Is it not possible to use the tap tool on DynamicMaps/Layers within a DynamicMap or do I miss something